# How do I control the spacing around my external svg

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I control  the position and space around my .svg. Right now when the page renders I get all this space around to the right and bottom of the .svg? 
My markup and styling looks like such:

```
<style>
  .fill-extra { fill: #686868; } 
</style>
```

In the `<body>` I have:

```
<svg class="fill-extra" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="svg_icons/extra_closed.svg#Layer_1"></use>
</svg>
```

the svg looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     enable-background="new 0 0 49.68 49.68" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M48.998,24.754c0,13.408-10.87,24.279-24.279,24.279c-13.41,0-24.279-10.871-24.279-24.279
    c0-13.409,10.87-24.279,24.279-24.279C38.128,0.475,48.998,11.345,48.998,24.754z M24.715,38.347h13.527l4.445-17.837l-1.871-3.976
    h-1.641l-0.467,2.572H24.715h-13.99l-0.466-2.572H8.62l-1.871,3.976l4.445,17.837H24.715z M24.717,28.697h4.93l1.666-1.053V23.96
    h-1.754v2.456h-4.842H19.88V23.96h-1.755v3.685l1.667,1.053H24.717z M24.717,17.074h12.209v-3.07H24.717H12.51v3.07H24.717z
     M24.717,11.942h7.999V9.837h-7.999h-7.996v2.105H24.717z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: We need more information.  Can you set up a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?  Does your svg file use 0 - 100 coordinates?

Comment: need jsfiddle to see what actually happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewBox is from 0,0 to 100,100 but the path's bounds are roughly 0,0 to 50,50.

You could make the viewBox smaller e.g. viewBox="0 0 50 50" which would keep the drawing the same size but make the contents look bigger. Or you could also make the width and height smaller which in conjunction with adjusting the viewBox dimensions could keep the drawing the same size whilst also getting rid of the empty space round it.